# How to change axis (x,y,z) position from center to left on three.js object rendering?

Tags: three.js

I want to move axis from center to left to show objects in the screen.. let me know is it possible to move it.

Comment: I want to show two objects in single scene. one have rotation and another one not having rotation.. i have extra space on left side. so that i want to move it

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to handle this:

1. Shifting the objects themselves (transformation along whatever axis is necessary)
2. Having your camera lookAt a position towards the right (giving the illusion of shifting left)

Since you only have your 2 objects, I would just shift them since it's easier to add that when you set their position to begin with